# Adding new metadata standard to GeoNetwork using only XSD file

Tags: metadata, geonetwork, standards

I've installed GeoNetwork v4.0.5 in a Tomcat server and I'm trying to add a new standard other than preinstalled ones. The problem is that I didn't found the schema plugin to do it, so I've been trying to install it manually using the XSD file. Specifically, I'm trying to install the GCMD DIF with the XSD file from https://git.earthdata.nasa.gov/projects/EMFD/repos/dif-schemas/browse/10.x/dif_v10.2.xsd.

Is it possible to install a new standard using only the XSD file?

I know that the preinstalled standards are using a lot more files and folders, but for this new one I didn't found a complete plugin to do so.

Comment: I don't think it's possible

Comment: Thank you so much.